# WRL SystemMediaTransportControls E_NOINTERFACE

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, controls, media, wrl

I'm trying to use the SystemMediaTransportControls in Visual C++ using WRL (toolkit v140) but I'm having issues with the following:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ABI::Windows::Media::ISystemMediaTransportControls> controls;
HRESULT hResult = ABI::Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory(Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Media_SystemMediaTransportControls).Get(), &controls);
```

The above code is returning E_NOINTERFACE but it's working if I follow the MSDN tutorial and activate a IUriRuntimeClassFactory.

Edit: I have initialized it prior to calling those functions.

Answer (score 0):

`ISystemMediaTransportControls` is an interface implemented on `SystemMediaTransportControls` class, not its activation factory. Did you intend the controls variable to be `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ABI::Windows::Media:ISystemMediaTransportControlsStatics>` instead?